# Toyota crown body tune up

Tags: toyota, body-work, body, bumper

Is it possible to upgrade exterior  looks of cars ? i.e. Upgrading the front look of a 2007 toyota crown to 2013 toyota crown

From this look [image: 2007 toyota crown]
[image: 2007 toyota crown]

To this look[image: 2013 toyota crown][image]

Is there anywhere online where i can buy upgrade body kits ? especially for the front bumper ?

Comment: Two things: Your last statement about "where can I buy" would place this question as off-topic. Secondly, considering you would be moving from a 2007 to a 2013 is a two vehicle generation jump, there's just about no *easy* way to do something like that. You'd find there's nothing which will match up as far as mounting any of it, let alone for the sizes of parts and such. While being similar in shape, the fenders will be quite a bit different from one to the other. Without major surgery, there's pretty much no way of doing what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Im certain it can be done but if a company doesn't already have a mass market solution then im also certain it would be cheaper to buy the car you want...

More than likely it's going to be a massive amount of custom work. Since you're asking you wont be able to do it yourself and it will be extremely expensive.